# Equity Risk Model using an autoencoder

Tags: pca, autoencoders, risk

I am trying to create a statistical equity risk model using an autoencoder in a similar fashion to how one would use PCA to derive the systematic and specific risk components of a stock's returns. I understand that the "specific return" (i.e. idiosyncratic return) is the reconstruction error of the PCA or the autoencoder. But I am unsure of how to feed the returns into the autoencoder. For example, let's say I have N = 3,000 stocks and T = 252 returns for each stock (i.e. the last year's trailing daily returns). I have attempted this several ways and I am able to get reconstruction error by reducing the N dimension or the T dimension. But I am unsure which is correct. My gut says I want to reduce the "N" dimension at each time point t=T in order to get the factor return of a few systematic factors, and then the deviation of a stock's return from these systematic factors is a stock's idiosyncratic (i.e. specific) return. If this is the case then how do I recover the systematic risk part for each stock at each time point?

For PCA, this is a bit easier as there is a lot of literature on how somebody can use PCA to estimate the systematic and specific components of an equity risk model using only a "panel of returns" for the given investment universe of interest. Calculate the covariance matrix, get the eigen values, etc. In the case that I mentioned above when T < N, people use asymptotic PCA (APCA) and this is well understood. Though I am new to building neural networks and I am unsure of how to best implement my risk model using an autoencoder or how to extract the systematic part of the estimated risk.

If it helps I am using pytorch in python. I can show any code that you might need to see if how I am messing this up. Here is the DAE that I am using.

```
class DAE(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden, n_output, mean=0.0, std=0.3):
    super(DAE, self).__init__()
    self.mean = mean
    self.std = std
    self.encoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden[0]),
        torch.nn.ELU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden[0], n_hidden[1]),
        torch.nn.ELU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden[1], n_hidden[2]),
        torch.nn.ELU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden[2], n_hidden[3]),
        torch.nn.ELU()
    )
    self.decoder = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden[3], n_hidden[4]),
        torch.nn.ELU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden[4], n_hidden[5]),
        torch.nn.ELU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden[5], n_hidden[6]),
        torch.nn.ELU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden[6], n_output)
    )

def add_noise(self, x):
    noise = x.new_tensor(x.data).normal_(self.mean, self.std)
    return x.add(noise)

def forward(self, x, train=True):
    training = train
    if training == True:
        x = self.add_noise(x)
    encoded_x = self.encoder(x)
    decoded_x = self.decoder(encoded_x)
    return decoded_x
```

I also found one "quasi-related" link titled, "How can I determine what features an auto-encoder cares about?" if this helps.

Comment: An auto encoder with no hidden units should implement projection onto 1st n principal components,where n is the encoder size. So make sure you get that working and check you get eg similar reconstruction error as PCA

Comment: @seanv507, this is a very helpful comment. Thanks for replying. I am able to get the same reconstruction error, and I am aware how to work through the math as to why the reconstruction error should be nearly identical with a linear activation function in my AE. I think what I am really asking is how to derive the variance of the dae.encoder(x_train). I can obviously regress my original data against the new compressed data and then use the regression framework to derive the fitted value variance. But is there another way?

Comment: I have some sample code showing what your asked. Should I post it below in the "answer" section, though it is nor really an answer to my original question? I am new to CV and Stack overflow, so apologies for these types of questions. Thanks, man.

Comment: Just add the code to your question .. with some explanation.

Comment: So maybe I don't understand your question. Isn't the systematic risk, decoded_x and specific risk = X - decoded_x

Comment: Yes, the systematic return is the decoded_x and the idiosyncratic (specific) return is X - decoded_x. Now that you mention it, I could just take the empirical variance of the time-series of decoded_x (after running this on a rolling basis to cover several cross-sections) and use this as the systematic risk. I should have seen this earlier. Thanks so much for your reply. If you think there is a flaw with this approach please let me know. Have a nice day.

Comment: No I don't see there is a flaw. basically you should create a setup  where applying methodology to PCA reconstruction gives you exactly same answers as your current PCA systematic risk. (so don't understand the rolling basis, but as long as its same methodology..!)